# Прозрачность дочерних элементов

Tags: html, css

Есть страничка http://jsfiddle.net/j4faJ/

Помогите пожалуйста, как избавится от прозрачности блока img?

Comment: как вариант http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/j4faJ/2/

Answer (score 2):

Задайте прозрачность через rgba(), вот так:

```
.two{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Вот живьем - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/FFErD/